# What is the gold ball in the rectangular box in the Ocean House Hotel in Vampire: the Masquerade - Bloodlines?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

In Vampire: the Masquerade - Bloodlines, on the second floor of the Ocean House Hotel, inside the first usable room on the left after you climb the ladder and exit the elevator shaft, there is a bedstand with a rectangular box on it that looks like some kind of velvet-lined collector's case, containing what looks like a gold ball, though it is difficult to get a good look at it because the case closes (presumably closed by a ghost) when you get within two yards or so of it.  The box and ball cannot be manipulated, so far as I can tell.

What is the deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the one around the 15 minute mark of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amSFpESP6NM)?

There's not enough detail to see in the video, but if I remember correctly, it's a small figurine in there. It's just a music box; it's what's playing the faint tinkling jingle you hear when you enter that hallway. Note that the music stops when you examine it and the lid slams shut. It doesn't mean anything special, it's just there to be creepy.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that had any particular meaning, I think it was just one of the many "poltergeist" animations used in the level. Slamming a door open and shut is a traditional poltergeist trick, and this is just a spin on that using a jewelry box. I don't think the gold sphere is anything related to the lore of that level, since the only jewelry-like object is the pendant, which is an entirely different object.